# 2 data columns - gender and numerical score

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft, if

In an Excel worksheet I want to identify whether a person has muscle weakness based on their gender and a numerical value. So for a male if their grip strength is less that 27Kg I want to return a value of "Sarcopaenia" and if a female has a grip strength of less than 16Kg I want to return a value of "Sarcopaenia". Otherwise I would like it to return "No Sarcopaenia" or blank. Female/Male is one column and the strength score is in another.

Is this possible?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: [This could be useful](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-with-and-or-and-not-functions-d895f58c-b36c-419e-b1f2-5c193a236d97)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

check this formula based on the image I posted.. change cells according to your cell data position

```
=IF(AND(B2="Male",C2<27),"Sarcopaenia",IF(AND(B2="Female",C2<16),"Sarcopaenia","No Sarcopaenia"))
```

[image: sample data in excel]